# My MacBook Pro Retina display backlight doesn't work

Tags: macbook-pro, display, backlight

The backlight on the display of my MacBook Pro 15 retina early 2013.

I have tried to make it brighter by pressing F2 but it didn't work, and when I bring a light from the back of the display exactly near the Apple logo I can see my login screen.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can try to reset the *SMC* by following the steps [here](http://thenextweb.com/lifehacks/2010/12/04/how-when-why-to-reset-the-pram-smc-on-your-mac/).

If that doesn't work it looks like your backlight is broken, and you should ask for a replacement if you still have Apple Care.